# why does 'getline' initialize the info?

Tags: c++, class, getline, strtok

```
while (!fin.eof())
{
    fin.getline(read, 49); subcnt++;    
    i_sequence = subcnt;                
    i_name = my_tok(read, "/");         
    i_price = atoi(my_tok(NULL, "/"));  
    i_quantity = atoi(my_tok(NULL, "/"));

    if (subcnt <= 10)
        loadlist[subcnt-1].setList(i_sequence, i_name, i_price, i_quantity);
}
```

`my_tok` is a function which I made to use instead of `strtok`.
The `loadlist` class contains information on an item.

I want this load function to read information line by line from an "ItemList.txt" file, and save written information to class.
The first loop is implemented as I want, but when it comes to the next loop and `fin.getline(read,49)` is called, all the info that previously saved is initialized.

I have no idea why the information is continuously changing when `fin.getline` is called.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Also, `while (!fin.eof())` is incorrect.

Comment: Post the smallest code example you can come up with that compiles, runs, and shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing code that opens the file and reads lines in a loop to  something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream fin("ItemList.txt");
    if (fin)
    {
        while (std::getline(fin, line))
        {
            // add code here to process each line
        }

        fin.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i_name = my_tok(read, "/");
```

The `my_tok` function returns a pointer into the buffer, right? And you've saved that pointer in `i_name`.

Well, since you saved a pointer into your buffer, when you change what's in the buffer, you change what values the pointer points to. You need to make a copy of the value you want to save and use a pointer to the copy.

Also, as others have pointed out, your use of `feof` is incorrect. It can't predict the future.